# How to determine a decision boundary calculated by libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

I'm using libsvm to classify data with a linear SVM, and I'd like to know the separating hyperplane it produces (i.e. the vector **w** and real b such that **x** is classified as a positive sample iff **w.x**+b>0). The tool svm-weight returns the coefficients of **w**, but how do I work out b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing ingredient is that: b (in wx + b > 0)  is -model.rho

Comment: IS svm-weight available for MATLAB too?